# Gravity Forms file upload leads to 404 in WordPress Admin

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm current having an issue with Gravity Forms. I have several forms with an upload function, but when people upload a file i can't view it in the backend. It just leads to an 404 error.

The file destination is: /index.php?gf-download=2018%2F10%2FRegnskabsskabelon-International-transport.pdf&form-id=7&field-id=101&hash=923ee8ba8c7bb431ea0c6b60ac4b0b8cd345b1ed452d8b4d3bddf1579ea961bf

I can't seem to find the file in FTP.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this error or find the problem.

What i've tried:

- Deactivating all plugins
- Resetting permalinks
- Using an standard theme
- Updating Gravity Forms.

The error still occurs

Hope you can help

Currently on Gravity Forms Version 2.4.6

Best Regards

Comment: https://docs.gravityforms.com/file-upload/

Comment: @Vishwa Don't really know why you think that would help me, but thanks :-)!

Comment: it shows basic steps to follow on file uplaod. also try checking your uploads folder write permissions

Comment: @Vishwa Write permission is 775 so that should be fine. I followed the steps and still the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with a client and just found a solution. It may not be universal though as most articles I found state that it is most likely a plugin conflict.

In my case it was simply an unwanted redirect of */index.html

There is already a redirect set in htaccess to route index.html to index.php and if there is a secondary redirect of index.html to a given page, you get a 404.

Hope this helps someone, as I haven't found any concrete solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I also just encountered this problem, and after head much scratching discovered that one possible cause is if you have moved Wordpress to/from its [own folder](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/) but **moved** the index.php file instead of **copying** it. Copying index.php back to its original location fixes the 404 error.